# no clean option in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-import

I found no option for clean project in build in `android studio`. what is reason for that? or is there different way to clean the project in `android studio`

[image]

Comment: Way is that only. 
Gradle build is working fine ?

Comment: i am getting error and I want to clean my project . but on option there.

Comment: please define the version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are looking a the correct directory. I also thought clean was missing when I looked under the root directory. Turns out it [see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8NO6.png) is located under the :app directory.

Open the Gradle side panel on the right. Select app->Tasks->build->clean

Answer (score 1):

This problem can occur when you import the root directory rather than the project file. If you imported the file, make sure you select the correct file:
[image: directoryselector]

Comment: what is `project directory`?